# Has anyone implemented a StackPanel equivalent using MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, stackpanel

I miss WPF / Silverlight's auto-layout controls (like StackPanel and Grid) when writing the equivalent UI for iOS using MonoTouch.

I'm hoping that instead of reinventing the wheel, someone has already created these :-)

I've found a [stackpanel](https://github.com/aaronbrethorst/StackPanel) for iOS github project but being a newbie to MonoTouch, I'm not sure how I would integrate the Obj-C code into the Mono project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've found a stackpanel for iOS github project

The stackpanel code seems based on `UITableView` and offers a simpler API for a specific case.

> I'm not sure how I would integrate the Obj-C code

In general you can compile existing objective-c into a library (using Xcode) and [create managed bindings](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types) for it. However in this case the code looks quite small so it might even be easier to translate to C# (and provide an API closer to Silverlight's StackPanel).

But I strongly suggest you to look at [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) which offers you a simpler API for  tables, including support for owner-drawn elements. It's also very easy to extend (using C#) to create your own elements. See the **Sample** project to see them in action.

Comment: Thanks Sebastien.  Yeah, the stackpanel is indeed based on UITableView and the "simpler API" isn't really worth the trouble for me because I have to compute the size of the subviews anyway (i.e. there's no magic autosizing).  I'll take a look at MonoTouch.Dialog - thanks!  (I've already found Miguel's code for simulating MessageBox and created a Silverlight-compatible code wrapper for it - quite handy!)

Comment: Um, the MonoTouch.Dialog stuff is amazing.  An enormous shortcut for creating iOS UI.  IMHO - between the attributed classes, fluent API, and JSON syntax, a more powerful / flexible UI builder than any I've seen.  THANKS for the pointer!